# Netezza /SQL ..temp table creation with random characters

Tags: sql, netezza

I am sure there is a very quick way of doing this, but I am a little stumped right now

Is there a way to select a bunch of characters such as('3232345','224225','234234234','533225') and insert each character into a new row of a temp table

I wanted to put these into temp table and compare it against another table in my database. I tried to import the characters in from the source excel file, but seems like I don't have permission to do so; So i tried to create the temp table as follows

```
with tablea as (
Select '3232345','224225','234234234','533225'
From testTable
)
Select * from tablea
```

I have to use testTable; because Netezza/ Sql doesnt like a select without a subsequent from. The above query returns a temp tablea with values but all in one row, i need the values that are comma separated to be in different rows; such as:

```
3232345
224225
234234234
533225

and not like  3232345,224225,234234234,533225
```

NOTE: I tried looking up the row_number() function but I think that function requires specific column values already defined in the table.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
with tablea as (
    Select '3232345' as val from testTable union all
    Select '224225' from testTable union all
    Select '234234234' from testTable union all
    Select '533225' from testTable
)
 . . .
```

Comment: Note, if you decided to use randomly generate numbers then I would use union as in the slight chance you generate the same numbers it would only select 1 of them (union all that would be).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, appreciate your quick response. i have given your answer a + 1 although, this does not completely solve my problem, I just gave an example with 4 characters, i have in some cases up to 400 of them, is this the only way to go about it?

Comment: @vbala2014 . . . If the values are coming from Excel, you can generate the code in Excel and copy it into the query.

Comment: ah i see, Good thought Gordon, thanks, i will give that a try

Answer (score 2):

Included with the INZA functions, there is a sample UTDF called split_to_rows that may do what you want.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>  select t.* from  table(split_to_rows('3232345,224225,234234234,533225', ',')) t;
 POS |    STR
-----+-----------
   1 | 3232345
   2 | 224225
   3 | 234234234
   4 | 533225
(4 rows)
```

If the INZA functions are installed, then you (or your administrator) can install this UTDF into your database like so:

```
[nz@netezza examples]$ cd /nz/extensions/nz/nzlua/examples
[nz@netezza examples]$ ls split_to_rows.nzl
split_to_rows.nzl
[nz@netezza examples]$ ../bin/nzl -d testdb split_to_rows.nzl

Compiling: split_to_rows.nzl
####################################################################
UdxName      =  split_to_rows
UdxType      =  UDTF
Arguments    =  VARCHAR(ANY),VARCHAR(ANY)
Result       =  TABLE(POS INTEGER,STR VARCHAR(255))
Dependencies =  INZA.INZA.LIBNZLUA_3_2_0
NZUDXCOMPILE OPTIONS: (--replbyval --unfenced --mem 2m --version 2)
CREATE FUNCTION
[nz@netezza examples]$
```

Comment: Interesting; Thanks ScottMcG, since the values are from an excel, i followed Gordons advice and solved the issue. But I will look right now to see if the INZA function is installed. Appreciate the input